# table row record click retrieve

Tags: jquery, html

how can i retrieve the first column in input box by clicking 1 row using j query? i already have a css style to hover the table row.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#record tr").click(data);
    });
</script>
```

```html
<table id="record">
    <tr>
        <TD>1</TD>
        <td>apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <TD>2</TD>
        <TD>banana</TD>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <TD>3</TD>
        <TD>orange</TD>
    </tr>
</table>

 <input type="text" name="input_1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Get text content using **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)** with callback, there you can get index and value as argument. Now get input element using index for that **[`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq)** will help and at last update value using **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#record tr").click(function() {
      $('td', this).text(function(i, v) {
        $("#insert_here input").eq(i).val(v);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<table id="record">
  <tr>
    <TD>apple</TD>
    <td>apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD>banana</TD>
    <TD>banana</TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD>orange</TD>
    <TD>orange</TD>
  </tr>
</table>




<div id="insert_here">
  <input type="text" name="input 1">
  <input type="text" name="input 2">
</div>
```

---

Or the same can be done using **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)** with callback

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#record tr").click(function() {
      var $td = $('td', this);
      $("#insert_here input").val(function(i) {
        return $td.eq(i).text();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<table id="record">
  <tr>
    <TD>apple</TD>
    <td>apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD>banana</TD>
    <TD>banana</TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD>orange</TD>
    <TD>orange</TD>
  </tr>
</table>




<div id="insert_here">
  <input type="text" name="input 1">
  <input type="text" name="input 2">
</div>
```